# Ardu IMU+ V3 drivers

Tags: ros, imu, imu-drivers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi community,
Has anybody tried to use an Ardu-IMU with ros ?
The new version Ardu-IMU V3 seems to be very interesting and powerful...
Its xmas-time and I like to buy one for my robot :-)

Cheers
Christian

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12306/ardu-imu+-v3-drivers/) by [Chrimo](https://answers.ros.org/users/361/chrimo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 390 on 2011-12-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As the ArduIMU is using an atmega328 and arduino IDE for development, it would probably be pretty easy to modify the provided source code to use rosserial_arduino and publish the data over an FTDI cable to a ROS powered computer.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-11-01**:
For those that stumble upon this page, rosserial cannot publish a full IMU message due to the hardware buffer length so your best bet is to publish data in a flat array and then republish it in the sensor_msgs/IMU message. :-)